# Expression Encoder 3 SDK screen capture C# sample?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, screen-capture, expression-encoder, expression-encoder-sdk

I am using VSTS 2008 + .Net 3.5 + C# + Microsoft Expression 3 SDK. I want to capture screen and output a wmv file. I tried hard but can not found C# samples from Google. Any reference samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong kind of tool, Expression Encoder is a transcoder.  It requires a video format as input and encodes it to a different output format.

You'll need to create a video of the screen first.  Capturing a screen shot is easy enough, Graphics.CopyFromScreen() can do that.  Generating a video would require doing this repeatedly and writing to a simple format like AVI.  The [code here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/csharp/avi/write_avi.html) could help.

Doing this fast enough so you capture enough frames per second is the ultimate challenge.  If that was easy then the companies that sell Jingo and Camtasia would quickly be out of business.

Comment: Hi Hans, any C# sample codes of using Expression Encoder SDK to write screen capture application?

Comment: The new SDK includes live pull push http://blogs.msdn.com/b/expressionencoder/archive/2011/01/28/10121701.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a late answer here, but you can use the free version of Expression Encoder 4 to do this (with a 10 minute time limit - for more than that you'll need to buy the pro version).

There is a sample in the SDK - SDK\Samples\ScreenCapture.

See http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/EncoderPro_Overview.aspx